# Emulating Heroku on local computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and Ruby on Rails and this may seem trivial. But I could not find the answer.

The Google App Engine has a web server application that emulates all of the App Engine services on local computer. Does Heroku have something similar?

Basically I want to run/debug RoR app on local machine before pushing it to Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku CLI has the `local` command to run your app locally. Without options, it will run the processes defined in the `Procfile` in the app root, using any environment variables defined in `.env`:

```
heroku local
```

For configuration options such as using different paths for `.env` and `Procfile` and `local` subcommands see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Answer (score 6):

If you are on the [Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) stack, there is a local utility called [`foreman`](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing_locally_with_foreman) that can read your `procfile` to simulate how it will run on Heroku. More info about it is on Dev Center here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman

Answer (score 2):

I use http://pow.cx/ and https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder for that. Is not emulating Heroku, but it allows you to set up a 'production' environment quickly.

Also, check http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments and consider if you need a staging deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like that exists for Heroku but to be honest you don't really need it. Develop locally, use Ruby 1.9.2 as that's the heroku default these days - keep in mind the constraints of Heroku http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-constraints. Use Postgres locally since that is what heroku shared DB is and you'll be off to a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar working with a Rails 7 app like this.

1. Create a file in the root of your app called `Procfile`
2. Add this to it (or similar, depending on your needs. I had this for a rails 7 app:

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

And this for a rails 6 app:

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
```

3. Then run

```
heroku local
```

The rails server should start.

#### Notes

- Heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-start-your-app-locally).